# MYSQL How to view user permission via the MySql Administration tool?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

We are using the MySql Administration tool in version 5.1.11 for ease of administration. But we cant change user permissions in the gui its just greyed out.
Picture related
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNogT.jpg

We tried a clean reinstall including removing left over registry entries.

Edit: NVM we fixed it

Comment: Check your permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL Administrator is a part of the old tools package (MySQL GUI Tools) which has been discontinued since several years. Instead there's now [MySQL Workbench](https://mysqlworkbench.org/) which combines all the separate tools from this old package into one tool (MySQL Query Browser, MySQL Administrator + MySQL Migration). Additionally it contains a graphical database design part (Modeling). The old tools cannot be used to access newer servers, hence I strongly recommend to use MySQL Workbench instead, which (at the moment) support all MySQL servers starting with 5.6 up to the latest 8.0 server.